# Wireshark/encryption and openvpn

Tags: openvpn, encryption, wireshark

I have a linux openvpn router and a home dsl modem. The dsl modem has port 1234 open and forwards it onto eth0 on the linux router.

I can connect to the router from a remote location no problem. All the traffic is coming through, I can surf the net from the vpn client etc. As a check I opened up wireshark on the client.

If I look at the protocol I can see a lot of UDP traffic, not much else... but I'm not seeing anything (as far as I understand) indicating that the data is being encrypted? Does that sound right or should I be looking at another interface? How is it best to test that the data is being encrypted? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, look at the data? You have wireshark, if you browse to google.ca and don't see a DNS request and a HTTP stream opening, and you still see the page being rendered, then it's a pretty big clue. Considering OpenVPN runs on UDP, it makes sense for you to see a ton of UDP traffic instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The UDP stuff made sense and the lack of DNS did too but I wanted to make sure. Sounds like I'm good. Thanks